# Can't export variable in .bash_profile ubuntu 18.04

Tags: .bash-profile, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to export some variable.

I create file `.bash_profile` and put inside `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local`

After it I reboot my ubuntu, login, but nothing happens.

My system is fresh ubuntu 18.04.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you're looking for, but I don't believe `.bash_profile` exists. Try adding that export command to `.profile` instead.

Aka, `echo "export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local" >> .profile`

(Tested on Debian Stretch; I don't use Ubuntu, but the fact you said "I create `.bash_profile`" is odd)

Comment: That worked? I thought (after posting) that maybe Ubuntu used a different layout than Debian and my answer was wrong. Apparently not.

Comment: BTW, Debian Stretch: root account: `cd ~ && ls -la .bash_profile` return: `/bin/ls: cannot access '.bash_profile': No such file or directory` ;)

Comment: this works for me

Comment: This answer contradicts the other answer on the page (which talks about the well-known `.bash_profile` file, and has more upvotes). This answer also contradicts `man bash`, section "INVOCATION", which talks about running `.bash_profile` on startup. Presumably this answer is, in some way, wrong, but switching from .bash_profile to .profile happens to work for some as-yet-unexplained reason. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Ah. The GUI login shell on Ubuntu is 'Dash', not Bash. Described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88149/8650)

Answer (score 3):

For your reference:

Below is `login shell startup file processing` diagram for different shells

[image: shell_startups]

(Credit for diagram is going to Shantanu Kulkarni who posted it in [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/gallery) gallery)