# Why does terminal output this every time I open it?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app

Every time I open Terminal, it outputs: `-bash: e: command not found`

[image]

Is that normal? If not, how could I remove this?

I'm using MacOs Mojave.

Comment: `bash` has complicated startup where it check and source its configuration/setup files to compare to other shells, check here places where this "hidden" *e* can live:  https://superuser.com/a/1344589/164837 In one of those places there also can be sourced `~./bashrc` from files shown in the diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to read this is that Bash is telling you that the command `e` cannot be found, so there is a script Bash is trying to run each time it opens, and that script contains the command `e`, and it doesn't recognize that.

Bash uses a profile to store commands that are run on every start, so check your `.profile` and `.bashrc` to see what is generating this error.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a line with a single e somewhere in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bashrc` file. All of these files are essentially a list of commands that are run upon opening up a new terminal.

To find and remove it, do the following commands to open up nano (a basic command-line text editor), search for the line with only an e, and comment it out by placing a # at the beginning of the line. Then save the file by pressing control-O and then enter, and exit by pressing control-X

```
nano ~/.profile

nano ~/.bash_profile

nano ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: You forgot to mention two more places: `~/.bash_login` and `/etc/profile` ;)