# How do I create a window as sudo from .screenrc

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have created a `.screenrc` file to automatically setup my various windows when I run `screen`. In one window I'd like to: switch to the root user, then change to a certain directory. I currently do this manually after creating a new screen window as follows:

- `sudo bash`
- `cd /etc/[dir]/`

How can I replicate this in `.screenrc`? I've read elsewhere that to run multiple commands on one line you can use `&&`, but I can't seem to get that to work with `sudo bash` (presumably because it creates a new bash instance and so the rest of the commands are either ignored or run in the new instance and then exited).

Comment: Add to the end `/root/.profile` your command `cd /etc/[dir]/` and do in screen only `sudo bash`. Make sure which [path](https://superuser.com/a/1344589/164837) your bash taking when starting

Comment: @Alex: If that comment were an answer, I'd downvote it because it unnecessarily affects _everything else_ that might run -bash as root, including console logins, SSH logins, `su -`, `sudo -i`, etc.

Comment: @harrymc I can't see any negative effects when switching from home directory to /etc, but I agree with you, it isn't nice solution. I think it better to do it with in *.screenrc* like `screen -t sudobash  
stuff "cd '/etc/[dir]';^M"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (presumably because it creates a new bash instance

Yes, it's the same with practically all user-switching mechanisms (`su`, `sudo -s`, etc.) but your variant makes it very obvious that a new `bash` process is being run.

> and so the rest of the commands are either ignored or run in the new instance and then exited).

No, the parent shell simply waits for `sudo` – and therefore for the new bash instance – to exit. (As it would with any other command.)

- Main shell runs `sudo bash` and waits for it to exit.

  - sudo runs `bash` and waits for it to exit.

    - bash gives you an interactive prompt in which you run your root commands.
    - When you type 'exit', bash exits.
  - sudo finishes waiting, cleans up and exits as well.
- Main shell finishes waiting, runs the next command if any.

---

However, you can tell any shell to execute commands non-interactively using its `-c` option which accepts a single command line: e.g. `bash -c "cd /etc && ls"`. (This is used behind the scenes by `ssh` or `su -c`.)

To get an interactive shell, just make sure the last command in that sub-command is one which runs an interactive shell. (That's quite a few bash instances deep, but not really a problem.)

```
sudo bash -c "cd /etc/foo && bash"
```